# Why Active Tab Redirecting to First Tab in React Material

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have successfully redirect the tab depending on the routes. My problem is when I'm on the second and succeeding tabs, when i refresh the browser, the active highlight on the tabs is going back the first tab?

Why is this happening? Pls check my code below

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box pt={4}>
          <div>{children}</div>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 640,
  },
}));

export default function Settings() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
          aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Users" component={Link} to="/users" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Products" component={Link} to="/products" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Sales" component={Link} to="/sales" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Users />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Products />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        <Sales />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I think that's how it work as it happens with me too.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (better on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to render same component at different routes

```
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path={"/"} exact component={TabComponent} />
        <Route path={"/users"} exact component={TabComponent} />
        <Route path={"/products"} exact component={TabComponent} />
        <Route path={"/sales"} exact component={TabComponent} />
   </BrowserRouter>
```

and you want to keep active tab depending on route path, you can achieve this by checking pathname in useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const pathname = props.history.location.pathname;
    switch (pathname) {
      default:
        setValue(0);
        break;
      case "/users":
        setValue(0);
        break;
      case "/products":
        setValue(1);
        break;
      case "/sales":
        setValue(2);
        break;
    }

  }, [props.history.location.pathname]);
```

Here working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-rgb-6o55s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this doesn't work. I dont you need query Params for this. Just normal Link would do

Comment: Then probably you want to render same component at each route, is that correct? if  so you can check pathname in relevant route, and set active tab according to the pathname,

Comment: I want to render <Users/> component if i click users menu, if i click products menu, then I will render <Products/> component

Comment: Well you should keep if activeTab somehow if you want to see recent tab when you refresh.
Otherwise it will be default  value because in useState it has 0 value thats why each render it will be zero.  You can keep activeTab value in query,pathname,localstorage...

Comment: If you dont have to have different pathname at each tab keeping activeTab in query is better approach because you will not re-render entire component.
This is a working example. https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-rgb-6o55s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you have to change pathname at each tab you should use this tab component at each routes component and  check pathname and set activeTab in useEffect

Comment: Thanks. Can you remove the queryParams, just wanted to look something like this `localhost:3000/users`. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220011/discussion-between-ubeyt-demir-and-joseph).

Comment: Hello. I have replied to the chat

Comment: I have replied again in chat

Comment: Hey  could you check it now ?

Comment: Good. But you notice there's a delay in the active highlight of the menu?

Comment: yes default is 0 and when component received props it is changing to what ever it is , thats why , its perfectly normal